# Why is this javascript regex not working to match 2 consecutive characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
x{n,}   

Where n is a positive integer. Matches at least n 
occurrences of the preceding item x.

For example, /a{2,}/ doesn't match the "a" in "candy", 
but matches all of the a's in "caandy" and in "caaaaaaandy".
```

and

```
(x)     

Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing groups.
```

Based on these 2 pieces of information, I'm assuming the following

```
elmt1 = 'aba'
elmt1.match(/(.){2,}/g)
```

would normally return `null` because I enclosed the character before and asked for it to return at least 2 occurrences of it.

and I assume that

```
elmt1 = 'aab'
elmt1.match(/(.){2,}/g)
```

would normally return `'aa'`

However, this method returns everything, the whole string, all the time.
I'm a bit confused by this, as it seems to me that it contradicts what's written in the documentation.

Can someone explain to me why this regex returns everything?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: No, `'aba'.match(/(.)\1+/g)` will return null. You did not use the backreference, and `.{2,}` here works almost the same way as `(.){2,}`, that is, it will match any chunk of string of 2 or more chars other than line break chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifier reapplies the group contents as regex, not as match. It's not that you will get `a`s because the `.` matched an `a`. You will get 2 or more of `.`, which means anything two times or more.

This is different from a back reference, like `\1`, which will refer to what group 1 matched.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are expecting `(.)` to remember the first character it matched and `(.){2,}` to match at least 2 occurrences of that particular character, but that's not how it works. `(.)` will remember the character it matched and save it, if you want to use it you have to reference it with `\1` (or `\2`, or `\3`... depending on which group you want).

Also, you should not apply a quantifier to a capturing group as the behavior it causes is almost always not the behavior you want (the group matches all the characters but only remember the last one).

What you want in this case is `(.)\1+`, meaning: match any character followed by the same character again, one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

`/.{2,}/` is equivalent to `/..|...|....|.....|…/`. Thus you regex will match anything, but single letters (or the empty string).